# converting user details stored in a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have tried converting the text file into a dictionary using the following code below:

```
d = {}
with open('staff.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        d[str(key)] = val
print(d)
```

The contents in the file staff.txt:

```
username1 jaynwauche 
password1 juniornwauche123
e_mail1 juniornwauche@gmail.com
Fullname1 Junior Nwauche
```

**Error: too many values to unpack**
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ***Error: too many values to unpack***: What did you not understand from the error message?

Answer (score 0):

According to your file, the last line you have three words and you want to split them by space so you will have three words but just two variables.

Comment: when i add the line.split(' ') it still returns the same error message , it stopped when i joined the fullname

Comment: and when i did that and added line.split(' ') it returned same error: too many values to unpack

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify the split condition. Right now you are splitting each character, there for you get a list with a lot of elements. Try `line.split(' ')` like this:

```
d = {}
with open('staff.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        (key, val) = line.split(' ')
        d[str(key)] = val
print(d)
```

This will split the lines where there's an space, so you get only words on the list.